# Understanding of build log file details

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I wanted to check the file contents which stores details, shown on 'Console Output' of a build. Hence I went to `Jenkins/jobs/<job-name>/builds/<build-id>` and opened `log` file but there saw text like following -

```
Started by user [8mha:////4GI+Z8Yd6iX0WFA5TlhAleQFdNY0RLkDxlbHNusZz70uAAAAlx+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJE/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAzWEgZu/dLi1CL9xJTczDwAj6GcLcAAAAA=[0mAdmin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[8mha:////4IvHH1F4rdNiYEQRW689PH+17TfIAyf+EFwlCQVhHObXAAAAoh+LCAAAAAAAAP9tjTEOwjAQBM8BClpKHuFItIiK1krDC0x8GCfWnbEdkooX8TX+gCESFVvtrLSa5wtWKcKBo5UdUu8otU4GP9jS5Mixv3geZcdn2TIl9igbHBs2eJyx4YwwR1SwULBGaj0nRzbDRnX6rmuvydanHMu2V1A5c4MHCFXMWcf8hSnC9jqYxPTz/BXAFEIGsfuclm8zQVqFvQAAAA==[0m[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[8mha:////4NFbLvEmn9YyKhIg6Ld8rDQi4ddGTuaay8012iYOmHOGAAAApR+LCAAAAAAAAP9tjTEOwjAUQ3+KOrAycohUghExsUZZOEFIQkgb/d8mKe3EibgadyBQiQlLlmxL1nu+oE4RjhQdby12HpP2vA+jK4lPFLtroIm3dOGaMFGwXNpJkrGnpUrKFhaxClYC1hZ1oOTRZdiIVt1VExS65pxj2Q4CKm8GeAAThZxVzN8yR9jeRpMIf5y/AJj7DGxXvP/86jduZBmjwAAAAA==[0m[Pipeline] node
Running on [8mha:////4IF6Mq4IOSKB/TBMBS4Y1o5+dLqeVx2Ap5w3zFMNVYzCAAAAnh+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJE/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAz2EgZh/eT83ILSktQifY3cxGIgrakPAHib2iPIAAAA[0mJenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Echo Pipeline
```

Is this correct file that I'm looking at? What is that messy thing in the file? If I want to convert that content in human readable format, what is a way?

Answer (score 0):

This is [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), and the following is a repo using python to convert the Jenkins logs to Human readable text: [Extract-Jenkins-Raw-Log](https://github.com/LarrysGIT/Extract-Jenkins-Raw-Log)